# SecureRandom.uuid slow to execute on Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, uuid

The first invocation of `SecureRandom.uuid` seems to be taking more than 5 seconds on Windows. I can't find anyone else with this issue - is it expected?

```
describe 'uuid' do
  it 'takes a while' do
    SecureRandom.uuid
  end
end
```

My setup is:

- Windows 7, 64 bit
- ruby 2.1.6p336 (2015-04-13 revision 50298)
  [x64-mingw32]

Comment: Ever find a solution? I have the same issue.